# Is it possible to use Jackson JSON to serialize a custom annotation?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have created a simple annotation for a class' methods. I would like to export the value of each annotation in JSON format.

So for example, I have an annotation:

```
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
@Target( ElementType.METHOD )
public @interface MyAnnotation
{
    int someInteger();
    String someString();
    String[] possibleTypes();
}
```

And then in my class I am annotating I have:

```
package com.clusin;
public class foo
{
    @MyAnnotation(someInteger = 1, someString = "bar", possibleType = { "a","b","c" })
    public int doSomeComputation(Object x, Object y)
    {
        //Do something here.
    }
}
```

Using reflection we can obtain a reference to these annotations at runtime.

So my question is: Given these annotations obtained at run time, is it possible to use jackson to serialize the values contained in the annotation?

I've tried annotating my annotation with @JsonProperty but the ObjectMapper throws a JsonMappingException when calling ObjectMapper#writeValueAsString.

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class $Proxy5     and no properties discovered to cre
ate BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable         SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider$1.failForEmpty(StdSerializerProvider.java:89)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider$1.serialize(StdSerializerProvider.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:242)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:1846)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:1473)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You might be able to write a custom serializer or subclass an existing Jackson one (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers). You could combine that with reflection tricks and store the annotations in the JSON as a field, I guess.

Comment: Could you give me example how it should look like? Could you show expected JSON for above example? Why you want to do something like that?

Comment: Michal, The keys in the outputted JSON should basically be the method names. Initially I was trying to annotate each method in the annotation via @JsonProperty(value = someInteger) for example.